# How fall back to default value if TFS build variables are not set?

Tags: powershell, tfs

I want to create a Powershell script that can be executed both on TFS within the context of a build agent and locally. On TFS, various [predefined build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts) are available, such as `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`. At the same time, the script is also available within the source tree, so I want to be able to run it locally, where those variables are not set. The shortest way I have found to fall back to a default value there is the following `Try..Catch` block with the unsettling long exception type:

```
Try {
    $SourcesDirectory = $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
}
Catch [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException] {
    $SourcesDirectory = "..\..\Local\Path\To\Sources\Directory"
}

Write-Output $SourcesDirectory
```

Is there a "nicer" way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could use a simple inline-if statement. I'm not sure if `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` has any side-effects, but with `$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY` this should work:

```
$sourcesDirectory = if($env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY) { $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY } else { "..\..\Local\Path\To\Sources\Directory" }
```

Comment: That's great news! Do you know where in the docs this equivalence of `$(Foo.Bar)` and `$env:Foo_Bar` is documented? I could not find it in the context my linked *predefined build variables* docs.

Comment: You can see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=powershell (scroll down and choose the PowerShell tab)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the variable to your local environment variables:

- Open CMD **as Administrator**
- Run this command: `setx Build.SourcesDirectory "C:\Path"`

[image]

Now the variables also available in your local machine and you don't need to `try/catch` or`if/else`, run the PowerShell script with the variable `$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY` and it will run in your local machine and in the build process as well.

Anyway, you should use `$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY` and not `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` to make it work on the build.